# LibGDX overwriting TouchUp

Tags: events, libgdx

I am trying to implement a simple button in LibGDX 0.9.8 version that would change the screens on TouchUp event. However, Eclipse shows me yellow underlining on my overwrite of TouchUp method saying that it is not used anywhere.

```
public void resize(int width, int height) {

    //Setting up stage failsafe
    if(_stage == null){
        _stage = new Stage(width, height, true);
    }

    _stage.clear();

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(_stage);

    TextButtonStyle style = new TextButtonStyle();
    style.up =  _buttonSkin.getDrawable("buttonUp");
    style.down = _buttonSkin.getDrawable("buttonDown");
    style.font = _font;

    _startButton = new TextButton("START GAME" , style);
    _exitButton = new TextButton("EXIT", style);

    ///
    ///PLACING BUTTONS
    ///

    //start button
    _startButton.setWidth(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 3);
    _startButton.setHeight(Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 4);

    _startButton.setX((Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 8) * 3);
    _startButton.setY((Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 5) * 3);

    _startButton.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

    _startButton.addListener(new InputListener(){

        public boolean touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                _game.setScreen(new World(_game));
                System.out.print("up");
                return true;
        }

    });


    //adding buttons to scene
    _stage.addActor(_startButton);
    //_stage.addActor(_exitButton);
```

I did some research on the web and there were couple of posts saying that in some version of LibGDX this event method is absent so I did check the library and found my desired method in there.

```
In InputListener class :/** Called when a mouse button or a finger touch goes up anywhere, but only if touchDown previously returned true for the mouse
 * button or touch. The touchUp event is always {@link Event#handle() handled}.
 * @see InputEvent */
public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
}
```

Anyone can see what am I doing wrong ? I am using the textbutton from com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;

Comment: Add the "@Override" annotation on methods that you expect to be overriding something in their parent classes (e.g., "@Override public boolean touchUp ...").  Eclipse should give you a better hint about what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [libgdx javadocs](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/), it seems that the method you're looking for is.-

```
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button)
```

without parameter `InputEvent event`. Make sure you remove that extra parameter, declare the method as `public`, and add the tag `@Override` as @P.T. suggested.-

```
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    super.touchUp(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    // Do your stuff here
}
```